# cannot start service freeradius ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, freeradius

i have a problem with start service freeradius. When i try to start service freeradius with command /etc/init.d/freeradius stars,it status fail

"**/usr/sbin/freeradius: error while loading shared libraries: libfreeradius-radius -2.1.8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**"

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

You have to give root permissions to freeradius
Use

```
$ sudo freeradius -X
```

or

```
$ start service freeradius
```